# Perl Regular Expressions to match a MD5 Hash?

Tags: php, regex, perl, validation, md5

Recently programming in PHP, I thought I had a working Perl regular expression but when I checked it against what I wanted, it didn't work.

What is the right expression to check if something is a MD5 has (32 digit hexadecimal of a-z and 0-9).

Currently, I have `/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/i`

Comment: Since when did hexadecimals go up to z?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**MD5:**

```
/^[0-9a-f]{32}$/i
```

**SHA-1:**

```
/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/i
```

**MD5 *or* SHA-1:**

```
/^[0-9a-f]{32}(?:[0-9a-f]{8})?$/i
```

Also, most hashes are always presented in a lowercase hexadecimal way, so you might wanna consider dropping the `i` modifier.

---

By the way, hexadecimal means base 16:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A   B   C   D   E   F  = base 16
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15 = base 10
```

So as you can see it only goes from 0 to F, the same way decimal (or base 10) only goes from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 13):

```
/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/i
```

Should work a bit better, since MD5 hashes usually are expressed as hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 9):

There is also the POSIX character class `xdigit` (see [perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html)):

```
/^[[:xdigit:]]{32}$/
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, an important point to consider is the fact that `$` can match `\n`. Therefore:

```
E:\> perl -e "$x = qq{1\n}; print qq{OK\n} if $x =~ /^1$/"
OK
```

Ooops!

The correct pattern, therefore, is:

```
/^[[:xdigit:]]{32}\z/
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier and faster than RegEx as recommended by PHP [Ctype Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.ctype.php) :

```
function is_md5($s){ return (ctype_xdigit($s) and strlen($s)==32); }
```

Answer (score -1):

@OP, you might want to use `/[a-f0-9]{32,40}/` , this can check for length greater than 32, such as those generated from sha1.